# How do I route all my traffic that doesnt go through tor through a vpn?

Tags: 12.10, networking, vpn, tor

I have a netbook running Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit acting as a wifi router based off this guide http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/   I would like to have it take in all data and send it through tor and vpn, if the data is tor-supported (TCP, Web Traffic, etc.) send it to tor and if the data is not tor-supported (UDP, whatever else) send it through vpn otherwise BLOCK IT. I'm unclear how to do this.  I don't have any vpn or tor set up yet. Also I do want to be able to ssh into this box at all times, right now I have ddclient updating dyndns.org to remedy this. Below is my set up as it stands now..

Internet<--->DNS<--->Cable Modem<--->Ubuntu Netbook/Wifi Router<--->All other devices